# The web server is running correctly but it cannot ping any ip address

Tags: linux, networking

I have a website hosting on a CentOS server, and this server itself is inside a VMServer ESXi. The web server is running correctly, i.e., the website can be accessed from the outside. But the server cannot ping/wget any ip address or URL (other than its own ip address), so I cannot run a web crawler on it. What are the possible reasons?

== Edit ==

`/sbin/iptables -L -v` outputs:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Something, somewhere is blocking your packets.  You diagnose this the same way you would any other network issue -- traceroute, check firewalls, check routes, tcpdump, check configs, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at possible outbound firewall settings/rules.

Answer (score 0):

Your CentOS server will most likely have a firewall. This may be configured to block output from your server. Please update your question with the (suitably redacted) output of

```
/sbin/iptables -L -v
```

If it's not your local firewall then check that there are no upstream devices doing the same thing.